# Another way to escape the address bar of a browser (popup)

Tags: html

As there are noway to hide the address bar, can we imagine a script or something else that would be able to "split" the window into two objects : the native window in one hand and the bar(s) in the other hand, and hide temporarily bar(s) behind the native window until the cursor comes over it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a seperate window which does not show the URL of the page loaded into it all the time.